# Найти слово с максимальным количеством гласных в строке

Tags: python

Дан текст "No items matched your query. But found these that sounded similar. "
Нужно посчитать количество гласных в каждом слове текста и вывести максимальное количество гласных в одном слове и это слово. Не знаю как вывести само слово, содержащее максимальное количество гласных.

```
import re

# Определяем список гласных букв
vowels = list("aeiouyAEIOUY")
# С помощью регулярного выражения разбиваем строку на слова
words = text.split()
number_of_vowels = []
max_vowels = 0


for word in words:
    number = sum(x in vowels for x in word)
    number_of_vowels.append(number)
    max_vowels = max(number_of_vowels)

print(number_of_vowels)
```

Comment: Как пишут в ответах, не то чтобы number_of_vowels был нужен, но `number_of_vowels = map(lambda word: sum(x in vowels for x in word), words)`. И да, если max_vowels считается как max(number_of_vowels), имеет смысл это делать после цикла for, а не внутри на каждой итерации.

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться регулярными выражениями:

```
import re

text = "No items matched your query. But found these that sounded similar. "
vowels = "aeiouy"

pat = r'(?i)[^{}]'.format(vowels)
```

---

```
In [45]: print(pat)
Out[45]: '(?i)[^aeiouy]'

In [46]: max(text.split(), key=lambda w: len(re.sub(pat, '', w)))
Out[46]: 'your'
```

Comment: можете свой минус обосновать? Или вы считаете нормальным из мести минусы ставить? (когда вам [критика ваших ответов не нравится](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/809489/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%bb%d1%8e%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0/809522?noredirect=1#comment1282815_809522))

Comment: @jfs, вы можете свой минус за этот ответ обосновать?

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы напечатать слово с наибольшим количеством гласных:

```
print(max(words, key=count_vowels))
```

где `count_vowels()` функция считает количество латинских гласных букв в слове, ожидая ввод в ASCII диапазоне:

```
def count_vowels(word, vowels="aeiouyAEIOUY"):
    return sum(1 for char in word if char in vowels)
```

Пример:

```
>>> text = "No items matched your query. But found these that sounded similar. "
>>> words = text.split()
>>> print(max(words, key=count_vowels))
your
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/brython-dev/brython/3.4.0/www/src/brython.js"></script><body onload="brython()"><script type="text/python">
from browser import document

def count_vowels(word, vowels="aeiouyAEIOUY"):
    return sum(1 for char in word if char in vowels)

@document["mybutton"].bind("click")
def on_click(event):
    text = document["text"].value
    words = text.split()
    print(max(words, key=count_vowels))
</script><textarea id="text">No items matched your query. But found these that sounded similar.</textarea><button id="mybutton">Запустить</button></body>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> text = "No items matched your query. But found these that sounded 
similar. "
>>> vowels = list("aeiouyAEIOUY")
>>> max(((word, sum(c in vowels for c in word)) for word in 
text.split()), key = itemgetter(1))
('your', 3)
```