# Проверить наличие строки в любом месте списка

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

Я работаю с библиотекой *sqlite3* и при отображении данных он выводит список с данными типа `tuple` и хотел бы проверить есть ли наличие строки в списке.

Код:

```
watcher_id = 116532
cursor.execute('SELECT watchers FROM posts')
w = cursor.fetchall()
```

Вывод в консоли при `print(w)`:

```
[(116532456743536896356746464,), (36572234134523356345445576,), (244684243545348545634,), (34574563542134146744757656785468,)]
```

Нужно проверить, содержится ли `watcher_id` в любом из них.

Comment: `print((watcher_id,) in w)`

Comment: я не понял зачем этот код?

Comment: чтобы проверить значение переменной watcher_id в списке w, который курсор вернет

Comment: @NurislomMakhkamjonkhojizoda, вы можете уточнить вопрос, чтобы ваш пример кода ему соответствовал?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
watcher_id = '116532'
w = [(116532456743536896356746464,), (36572234134523356345445576,), (244684243545348545634,),
     (34574563542134146744757656785468,)]
for i in w:
    if watcher_id in str(i[0]):
        print(True)
    else:
        print(False)
```

---

Вывод

```
True  # 116532456743536896356746464
False # 36572234134523356345445576
False # 244684243545348545634
False # 34574563542134146744757656785468
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно так:

```
In [266]: watcher_id_str = str(watcher_id)

In [267]: any(watcher_id_str in x for x in map(str, w))
Out[267]: True
```

или так:

```
In [271]: str(watcher_id) in '|'.join(map(str, w))
Out[271]: True
```

Comment: вариант с `''.join()` неправильный: `'12' in ''.join(['1', '2'])` хотя `not any('12' in x for x in ['1', '2'])`

Comment: @jfs, в общем случае да, но в данном случае `cursor.fetchall()` - возвращает список кортежей, поэтому при преобразовании в строку у нас будут скобки в качестве разделителей

Comment: не ясно к чему грязные хаки с поиском в текстовом представлении кортежей, когда есть методы вроде: `(watcher_id,) in w` или `select  1 from posts where watchers = :watcher_id limit 1`

Comment: @jfs, вы пример в вопросе видели?

Comment: @jfs, не стоит давать советы и ставить минусы если не поняли  вопрос...

Comment: вместо того чтобы минусы ставить на неотносящихся к делу вопросах, адекватная реакция на критику, которую вы ошибочной считаете, содержала бы вашу словесную интерпретацию вопроса (что полезно в ответ добавить) в рамках которой, ваш ответ правильный (по вашему мнению)—вы даже можете быть правы в вашей интерпретации, но это не оправдывает [мелкое пакостничество](https://goo.gl/ev42v4).